# Как получить нужную часть url?

Tags: javascript

Как получить нужную часть url без `location.search`? Например `?article=new` из `http://site/index.php?article=new`. У меня такой код но получаю `article=new` без `?`. Как получить `?article=new`

```
var href = window.location.href;
var index = href.split('?');
var url = index[0];
```

Получаю `article=new`

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = this.href;
    var get = location.search;
});
```

А так ничего не получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var s = "http://site/index.php?article=new";
var path = "?" + s.split("?")[1]   // "?article=new"
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var url = new URL('http://site/index.php?article=new');
var search = url.search;    // ?article=new
```

А не работает ваш код, потому что в контексте вашего обработчика, `this` указывает на элемент `body`, а вовсе не объект `Window`. Вместо `this`, вам нужно было использовать внутри обработчика запрос `$(window)`:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var location = $(window)[0].location;

    var url = location.href;
    var get = location.search;
});
```